# Using little/low/big/large in a sentence

Tags: word-usage

I was writing a term paper and got myself a bit confused with the use of 'little'/'low'/'big' etc. 
The sentence is:
'Although in smaller member countries, with fewer seats to distribute, the number of elected candidates per group is ***little***, the size of our two groups is ***big*** enough to assure the accuracy of our estimates'

Although I have written it in this way, the sentence just feels somehow incorrect. I would greatly appreciate any suggestions. Thank you in advance.

Comment: *The number of ... is **little*** sounds wrong. The number can be *small*, not little, but then you'd repeat *small* twice which doesn't sound particularly nice either

Comment: How about *Although in smaller member countries, with fewer seats to distribute, the number of elected candidates per group is **low**, the size of our two groups is **large** enough to assure the accuracy of our estimates*?

Comment: @ArmenԾիրունյան indeed, 'little' does sound just wrong, and makes the sentence to sound strange. Thank you for your comment!

Comment: @MamtaD  thank you for the suggestion! I think i will opt for it.

Comment: The sentence doesn't make sense anyway. It's needs an `and` or `where` in there somewhere instead of a comma, or a full stop after little.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Small* would be good but would lead to **repetition**, which can be avoided by using some other similar words.

To avoid the repetition, you can write it this way:

> Although in smaller member countries, with fewer seats to distribute,
>   the number of elected candidates per group is **low**, the size of our two
>   groups is **large** enough to assure the accuracy of our estimates?